# Foco no primeiro elemento da validação - jQuery

Tags: jquery

Olá,

Com a função abaixo, eu valido campos obrigatório.

Neste caso, eu não uso esta função para submeter o formulário, mas sim para adicionar items ao objeto.

Porém, eu quero dar foco no primeiro elemento obrigatório.

Algo do tipo: 
`$('#elemento')[0].focus`.

Podem me ajudar?

```js
campos = ['#txt-cep', '#txt-logradouro', '#txt-bairro', '#txt-cidade', '#txt-uf'];

if (campo_obrigatorio(campos)) {
    //faça algo
}

function campo_obrigatorio(campos) {
    var ret = true;
    for (i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {
        var $form_line = $(campos[i]).parent();
        if (!$(campos[i]).val()) {  
            if (!$form_line.hasClass('error focused')) {
                $form_line.addClass('error focused');
      //$form_line.find($(campos[i]).focus());
             }
             ret = false;
        }
        else {
            if ($form_line.hasClass('error focused')) {
                $form_line.removeClass('error focused');
            }
        }
    }
    return ret;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O erro está nesta linha:

```
$form_line.find($(campos[i]).focus());
```

O `.focus()` deve ficar fora dos parênteses do `.find`:

```
$form_line.find($(campos[i])).focus();
```

Porém, da forma que está fazendo não irá selecionar o primeiro, mas sempre o último.

Neste caso, selecione o primeiro elemento pelas classes após a conclusão do laço `for`:

```
$(".error.focused:eq(0) input").focus();
```

**Exemplo:**

```js
campos = ['#txt-cep', '#txt-logradouro', '#txt-bairro'];

if (campo_obrigatorio(campos)) {
    //faça algo
}

function campo_obrigatorio(campos) {
    var ret = true;
    for (i = 0; i < campos.length; i++) {
        var $form_line = $(campos[i]).parent();
        if (!$(campos[i]).val()) {
            if (!$form_line.hasClass('error focused')) {
                $form_line.addClass('error focused');
             }
             ret = false;
        }
        else {
            if ($form_line.hasClass('error focused')) {
                $form_line.removeClass('error focused');
            }
        }
    }
    
    $(".error.focused:eq(0) input").focus();
    
    return ret;
}
```

```css
.error.focused{
   background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
   <p>
      <input type="text" id="txt-cep" value="texto">
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" id="txt-logradouro">
   </p>
   <p>
      <input type="text" id="txt-bairro">
   </p>
</form>
```

Comment: obrigado pelo retorno, mas se eu manter `$(campos[i])` vai focar sempre no ultimo elemento obrigatório e seu eu alterar para `$(campos[0])` irá focar somente no primeiro campo, sendo que se eu preencher o primeiro campo, o foco não passa para o segundo campo obrigatório.

Comment: Melhor, faltava o return false, agora deu certo.

Porem a classe `error focused` só se aplicou ao campo com foco, teria como aplicar em todos os campos obrigatórios e manter o foco no primeiro camo não preenchido ?

Comment: Alterei a resposta.

Comment: Funcionou muito bem, obrigado @Sam..